Looking for a TV series about becoming invisible
The show is about two teenage friends who find a formula in an old book that makes objects invisible. To make the invisibility potion, they find an old book in the library and borrow chemicals from school. They use the instructions in the book to make the potion. The reason the author of the book couldn't make the potion is because the lab equipment at the time wasn't advanced enough to do so.
When someone who is invisible is sprayed with water, they become visible again.
The show has a very positive tone and the two high school characters are not at all criminal or detective-like.
The teenager who found the formula didn't want anyone else to know about it.
In one episode, he experimented with the invisibility potion so much on himself that no matter how much water he used, he couldn't become visible again. He also has an older brother who wants to catch him. In the end, he spends a long time in the bathtub and his body becomes visible in parts every few minutes with hot water.
In another episode, someone else figures out the formula and wants to use it for military purposes.
The main character makes himself invisible and infiltrates their lab, but they identify him. The scientist there says that he has opened a new chapter in chemistry.

The water part sounds  lot like Now you see him, now you don't

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Out of Sight (1996-1999)

The 12-year-old boy genius Joseph (Joe) Lucas discovers an experiment in an old diary and a copy of The Invisible Man by H. G. Wells. With the help of a friend (Ali Pantajali) he recreates the experiment and makes a substance to turn people and things invisible by simply spraying it with the trademark green-bottled solution. The effects are reverted, whether intentionally or not, by the appliance of water or by waiting for a couple of minutes. Joe decides not to tell anybody except Ali of his invention. This is the reason for some strange moments for Joe and his family.

Found with a search for tv show kids formula invisible

There's an episode in German at https://youtu.be/_DtN6owOYfw?si=SrZ6hBef7oYsqSVH
